# Running ASP Classic on IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I need to do some work on an old ASP Classic site, so I’m trying to host it on my IIS, but when I try load a page I get:

> An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
>
> If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.

When I follow the link, it takes me to a Microsoft site and talks about running ASP Classic on IIS 7, but none of the pages help and nothing I found on Google will get it to work. I have all the elements under turn Windows features on and off - IIS - WWW services - app dev features.

Answer (score 44):

This was bugging me earlier today and it turned out I had an error in my script.

This assumes you have installed the ASP/ISAPI extensions via the Control Panel's "Add/Remove Windows Features."

By default, errors will not be sent to the browser. To enable sending errors to the browser, go to the site in your IIS manager. Double click the ASP icon and expand "Debugging Properties." Set "Send Errors to Browser" to `True`.

[image: Enabling Send Error To Browser]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and it turns out you need to set application pool to classic .net for it to work.